# How do I get rid of this annoying blank popup

Tags: html, popup

Sorry about the wording for my question title.

I have a basic HTML anchor tag that when clicked it is suppose to bring up a dialog box to download a file from a differnt website.
I am using an attribute of `target="_blank"` so that when my hyperlink is clicked, I don't navigate away from my main window.

This is all the easy part (if it was so easy I wouldnt be here though).

When I do the above though, and click on the hyperlink, an annoying blank window pops up with my download dialog box behind it.

How do I get rid of that annoying blank window and keep only my download dialog box on the screen?

Below is the HTML I'm working with...

```
<a href="http://www.fake-domain-name.com/downloads/setup.msi"       
   target="_blank">

       <img src="images/download.png" alt="download file"/>

</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lose the `target="blank"`.

You know that is **supposed** to open a new window/tab, do you?

Comment: Aww man... I wish I could down vote my own question!!!!  

The annoying blank window only pops up when I am on my local machine.  
the problem doesnt occur when the site is live on the web....

Sorry to waste your time.